# How can I display a dynamically tiled raster layer in React Native using Mapbox or other alternatives?

Tags: react-native, mapbox-gl-js, rasterizing

I need to display a raster layer using dynamic tiling in a react native project. I have a Tiff file that's over 500mb large, I need to upload this file to a tiling server from where I can load it as a raster layer in my react native project.

I have read about dynamic tiling but not able to understand how to implement the Mapbox tiling server. Are there any other better alternatives or an easier way to do this?